# The result if order of two filter are reversed

Tags: filtering

1. Apply the Composite Laplacian Filter first, then apply the gaussian filter.
2. Apply the gaussian filter first, then apply the composite laplacian filter.

My work as below:
Here we assume the original image is function $f(x,y)$
$$ (1): (f-\nabla^2f)\ast G = f \ast G - \nabla^2f \ast G$$
$$ (2): (f \ast G) - \nabla^2(f \ast G) = f \ast G - f \ast \nabla^2G $$

I am wondering the statement $\nabla^2f \ast G = f \ast \nabla^2G$ is true or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, (linear) derivatives and convolutions may commute, as explained on [Wikipedia-Convolution/Properties/Differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Differentiation). This is a major "operation-saving" property: if one wants to differentiate many images and convolve then with a fixed kernel (here a Gaussian), one can convolve the images with the differentiate kernel.

You don't have to differentiate all images, just the kernel once.

*Caveat*: what is written above could be taken with care, notably when derivatives don't exist theoretically, or with subtleties in implementing derivatives.

Comment: Therefore the equality I mentioned is correct? Since I need to prove / disprove this. As you mentioned, seems this is equal